# Type of Series (Pandas) in to_datetime() method

Tags: pandas, datetime, types, series

I have a data frame with one Date column. 
Using dt=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) to convert it into datetime format:
Results is:
Name: Date, Length: 198900, dtype: datetime64[ns]. However when I want to change the format using datetime.datetime.strptime('%B %d, %y',dt), I get the following error:
TypeError: strptime() argument 2 must be str, not Series
I wonder what dtype: datetime64[ns] means here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pandas function [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

And then:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B %d, %y')
```

Or:

```
df['Date_New'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B %d, %y')
```

One row solutions:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%B %d, %y')

df['Date_New'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%B %d, %y')
```